# Adding Parsekit To An Xcode Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks, compiler-errors, parsekit

I am trying to add the [Parsekit](http://github.com/itod/parsekit/) framework to my OSX Xcode project. I've never added a 3rd party framework before and I can't get it to work right.

I dragged the included Xcode project into my 'Groups & Files' pane and chose to Add it to my project. I then dragged `Parsekit.framework` underneath the `Link Binary With Libraries` heading. Then I double-clicked my target app and added `Parsekit` as a Direct Dependency. I also added `libicucore.dylib` as a Linked Library (as it says to do this on their site). Finally, in the Build settings tab of my target info I set the `Header Search Paths` to `/Users/path/to/include/directory` and the `Other Linker Flags` to `-ObjC -all_load`.

Running this as a debug build work fine with no errors. However, when I build my app to release and then try to run the executable created, the app fails to load with the following error message:

> MyApp cannot be opened because of a problem. Check with the developer to make sure myApp works with this version of Mac OS X.

Here is the dump from the crash reporter:

> Process:         MyApp [11658] Path:
>   /Users/Garry/Programming/Xcode/Mac/MyApp/build/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
>   Identifier:      com.yourcompany.MyApp
>   Version:         ??? (???) Code Type: 
>   X86-64 (Native) Parent Process: 
>   launchd [135] Date/Time:
>   2010-05-24 17:08:08.475 +0100 OS
>   Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.3 (10D573)
>   Report Version:  6Interval Since Last
>   Report:          133300 sec Crashes
>   Since Last Report:           3 Per-App
>   Crashes Since Last Report:   3
>   Anonymous UUID:
>   DF0265E4-B5A0-45E1-8B71-D52A27CFDDCA
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT
>   (SIGTRAP) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000002, 0x0000000000000000
>   Crashed Thread:  0
>
> Dyld Error Message:   Library not
>   loaded:
>   @executable_path/../Frameworks/ParseKit.framework/Versions/A/ParseKit
>   Referenced from:
>   /Users/Garry/Programming/Xcode/Mac/MyApp/build/Release/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
>   Reason: image not found
>
> Model: MacBookPro5,5, BootROM
>   MBP55.00AC.B03, 2 processors, Intel
>   Core 2 Duo, 2.53 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.47f2
>   Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce 9400M, NVIDIA
>   GeForce 9400M, PCI, 256 MB Memory
>   Module: global_name AirPort:
>   spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme
>   (0x14E4, 0x8D), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0
>   (5.10.91.27) Bluetooth: Version
>   2.3.1f4, 2 service, 2 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service:
>   AirPort, AirPort, en1 Network Service:
>   Ethernet Adaptor (en6), Ethernet, en6
>   Serial ATA Device: Hitachi
>   HTS545025B9SA02, 232.89 GB Serial ATA
>   Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS23N USB
>   Device: Built-in iSight, 0x05ac 
>   (Apple Inc.), 0x8507, 0x24400000 USB
>   Device: Internal Memory Card Reader,
>   0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8403,
>   0x26500000 USB Device: IR Receiver,
>   0x05ac  (Apple Inc.), 0x8242,
>   0x04500000 USB Device: Apple Internal
>   Keyboard / Trackpad, 0x05ac  (Apple
>   Inc.), 0x0237, 0x04600000 USB Device:
>   BRCM2046 Hub, 0x0a5c  (Broadcom
>   Corp.), 0x4500, 0x06100000 USB Device:
>   Bluetooth USB Host Controller, 0x05ac 
>   (Apple Inc.), 0x8213, 0x06110000

After building the app, in addition to the executable file, Xcode is also creating a file called `MyApp.app.dSYM`. Any idea what that is??

I am developing with Xcode 3.2.2 on an Intel MBP running 10.6.3.

Many thanks for any help offered.

**Edit: New problem!**
Many thanks to diciu for your suggestions - initially I thought they had solved the problem. However, I copied the compiled app over to my wife's Macbook (Intel, running 10.6.3) but it won't launch. Instead I get the following error message:

You can't open the application MyApp because it is not supported on this type of Mac.

In the Build settings of MyApp, I have `Valid architectures` set to `i386 x86_64` so it should work. What could this be caused by?

**Edit: Problem solved**
I had inadvertently checked the `Build active architecture only` flag in the Build settings. Unchecking this fixed my problem. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to create a "copy files" step under your target.

Right click your target, choose "Add" -> "New Build Phase" -> "New Copy Files Build Phase".
For destination choose "Frameworks".

Under the newly created build phase, drag your Parsekit framework.

The dsym package from your build directory contains [debugging symbols](https://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/symbolizingcrashdumps.html).

Answer (score 1):

Developer of ParseKit here.

The method for doing this has changed in Xcode 4. See my answer to [How to embed ParseKit as a private framework in a Mac App bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9658158/34934) for detailed instructions on how to do this in Xcode 4 for a Mac App.