# Xcode: Dragging a Project to a Workspace shows tiny .xcodeproj file in Project Navigator. What's wrong?

Tags: xcode, macos

**Setup**:

Xcode 4.3.1 (or 5.x)
OS X 10.7.3

I have reproduced this issue on two separate late-model Macs with this setup.

**Steps**:

1. Create a new Mac "Cocoa Application" Xcode Project. `File > New > Project…` Name it "MyApp".
2. Create a new Workspace: `File > New > Workspace…` Name it "MySuite".
3. Drag `MyApp.xcodeproj` file from the Finder into the Project Navigator of "MySuite" Workspace.

**Expected**:
The Project Navigator of the "MySuite" Workspace should now show a **full sub-Project** for "MyApp" with Source, Targets, etc.

**Actual**:
"MySuite" Workspace Project Navigator shows a tiny `MyApp.xcodeproj` item in the Project Navigator. (see screenshots)

---

**Dragging:**

[image: Dragging MyApp.xcodeproj to the Workspace]

**Result:**

[image: Result]

What am I doing wrong in trying to add a Project to a Workspace?

Comment: Do you have the project you're dragging open in another window?

Comment: Yes. Wow. Closing the other Project window and trying again fixed it. I guess that's a bug? You rock! Would you like to post your answer below for credit? :)

Comment: It's actually supposed to work that way. I've seen alerts before saying you have this project already open, so you can't open it again. Really silly, but I guess it makes sense.

Comment: Yes, it's no different than trying to drag a file to another folder when it is currently open by another program. Can't be done. Right ?

Comment: Ric, I honestly would not agree. At the very least some warning dialog of what's going wrong would be helpful. Anyhow, now that I know the issue, I can easily work around. :)

Comment: 8 years later this helped me, this really odd behavior without any warning/info is still a present problem, after a decade... Damn.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

Be sure you don't have the project already open in another window. Xcode only lets you open a project one time. I've made this mistake a lot when working on a framework then trying to add it to an application.

Simply close the project you're trying to drag in's window and everything will be happy.

Comment: I have heard a unconfirmed rumor that this will be fixed in Xcode 4.4.

Comment: When I drag a project from another folder is usually causes the app to crash without an apparent reason.Maybe on the plist there is the old path and this causes the crash.

Comment: OMFG seriously??? AAAAAARRRRGGGGHHHHHH I WANT THE LAST 30 MINUTES OF MY LIFE BACK!!!! Thanks for the solution!

Comment: Damn it Apple 