# ParseKit framework in Xcode is red, won't build

Tags: xcode4, parsekit

I'm trying to add ParseKit to a new command line project in Xcode, but the framework shows as red in the Project Navigator. When I try to build, I get this error

`error: /Users/acdlite/Xcode/Chemistry Parser/../parsekit-trunk/build/Debug/ParseKit.framework: No such file or directory`

I've followed the directions given by the developer in this answer: [How to embed ParseKit as a private framework in a Mac App bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649537/how-to-embed-parsekit-as-a-private-framework-in-a-mac-app-bundle/9658158#9658158).

To my knowledge, red indicates that the file is not at the specified location. The file inspector says it should be located at `/parsekit-trunk/build/Debug/ParseKit.framework`, which actually doesn't exist if I try to navigate there in the Finder. So then where *is* it located? I have no idea.

I've followed all the steps from scratch like a dozen times now, including checking out the code via SVN. It's driving me crazy, and I feel like an idiot. I wish I could be more specific but I am truly lost as to where to go from here.

Comment: Just a guess: your project's directory name has whitespace in it (`Chemistry Parser`). This is usually a bad idea. If all paths in the Xcode Target's build settings are not quoted, you will run into problems similar to this. (Although I'm not certain that's the problem here).

Comment: I renamed it, but I'm still getting the same error. Thanks for the tip, though.

Comment: I'm the author of the "How to embed" answer you referenced (and developer of ParseKit). I looked back at that answer, and it was missing 3 steps. I added them just now. Please go back to that answer and see steps 9-11. Basically, I think you probably haven't set ParseKit as a dependency of your Target (which means ParseKit is not being built first, therefore it cannot be linked to).

Comment: When I get to step 11, the dialog says "No items are available." I can't drag and drop, either.

Comment: If ParseKit is not available as a dependency, then you have not correctly added it to your project. You've missed something in steps 1-10.

Comment: Well I truly don't know what the problem is, because I've done steps 1-10 from scratch, meticulously, about 20 times now. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after at least 20 attempts I eventually got it working. Mostly, I followed the steps given by the developer in this answer: [How to embed ParseKit as a private framework in a Mac App bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649537/how-to-embed-parsekit-as-a-private-framework-in-a-mac-app-bundle/9658158#9658158)

However, following the steps exactly didn't work. For the life of me, I couldn't get the ParseKit framework to show up as an option when I attempted to add it as a dependency of my Target. Xcode would just say "No filter results found." So I skipped that step. I also did *not* add a "Copy Files" build phase. Doing so resulted in a dependency error.

This was way harder than it should have been, and I don't know if that's because I'm stupid or Xcode is poorly designed. Probably a combination of both.

By the way, I'm using Xcode version 4.6.1 (4H512).