# Parsekit and Cocoapods

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods, parsekit

Trying to use ParseKit in a project via cocoapods, but I am encountering linking errors.
All other cocoapods libraries work fine.

### Podfile

```
platform :osx, '10.7'

pod 'ParseKit', '0.7'
```

### Error

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PKToken", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PKTokenizer", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: This is a link error. Are you sure you're linking to ParseKit in your Xcode Target's `Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries`?

Comment: I'm using cocoapod so I thought I shouldn't have to add ParseKit in the Link Binary with Libraries.  I checked and it's not ParseKit isn't listed, but cocoapod is.  Using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649537/how-to-embed-parsekit-as-a-private-framework-in-a-mac-app-bundle/9658158#9658158 works, but I wanted to use cocoapod.

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with the 0.7 podspec for ParseKit, it doesn't quite include all the necessary files.
I had the same issue and fixed it by changing the podspec to read.

```
s.source_files           =  'include/**/*.{h,m}', 'src/**/*.{h,m}', 'lib/MGTemplateEngine/MGTemplate*.{h,m}', 
                          'lib/MGTemplateEngine/ICUTemplateMatcher.{h,m}', 
                          'lib/MGTemplateEngine/*DeepMutableCopy.{h,m}'
```

You can clone the github repository and copy the podspec into it, make this change and then use the :path option for the pod to use the local copy

Comment: If this fixes the issue correctly it would be awesome if you could submit this change as a pull request to the [specs repo](http://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/)

Comment: The specs repo podspec has been updated recently, it looks like it might have solved this also